# is chrome app permission "unlimitedStorage" deprecated?

Tags: memory-management, google-chrome-app

I read in google manual (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#persistent) that:

"You can ask for the unlimitedStorage permission in the manifest file for an app or extension. At installation, the user is informed of permissions required by the app or extension. By proceeding with the installation, the user implicitly grants permission for all pages whose URLs are listed in the manifest.json file."

However there is no difference in the permissions information upon installation if I have "unlimitedStorage" in my manifest file or not. Also, my appcache is not granted any more space than a few MB, if even that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However there is no difference in the permissions information upon installation if I have "unlimitedStorage" in my manifest file or not.

Not all permissions generate user-visible warnings. `unlimitedStorage` is granted silently - if you request it.

**App Cache, however, *is* deprecated as a technology.** `unlimitedStorage` applies to various storage mechanisms, but the quote from the documentation makes me think it never applied to App Cache. I'm not 100% sure though.

Also, observation: you say in multiple questions that you're working with Chrome Apps; however, all your app "shell" does is to wrap a website in a `<webview>`. You should specify that, as a whole different set of rules apply (it's not App code, it's web code running in something that's not-quite-Chrome).

Further, from the docs:

> Note: Web storage APIs like LocalStorage and SessionStorage remain fixed at 5 MB.

Since your "app" is just web code, it seems that this limit applies. You should maybe look into newer web storage technologies (e.g. Service Worker caches).

Comment: I am aware that appcache was considered deprecated within a few years of introduction, and now replaced by the (according to MDN) still experimental web workers. However, appcache works fine for my purpose, the app runs smoothly in chrome, all I need is to wrap it in a kiosk environment but it seems impossible. Not so keen on reprogramming the entire slideshow engine to web workers. And then THAT is considered deprecated in two or three years... =)

Comment: Oh... what is the appropriate environment for creating a chromebox kiosk wrapper for a webapp like mine (appcache)?

Comment: It's still supported on Chrome OS, but Chrome OS only.

Comment: You suggest service workers as an alternative to appcache. Do you know whether that restriction of 5mb would still apply? Would I have to place all the cache handling code inside the chrome app rather than in the web app for it to work, or would service workers in the web app be allowed to allocate the "unlimited storage"?

Comment: See [Offline Storage for Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) article for guidance. Of note: I'm not 100% sure service workers will actually work in a `<webview>`.